# tinymce - how to auto-convert text to a bullet when user types '* '

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I'm trying to set up my tinymce editor to automatically convert certain strings into formatted text.   For my first attempt, I am auto-creating bullets when I type '* ' (maybe there is a plugin that does this?)

Here is the code I am starting with:

```
editor.on('KeyUp', function(e){
    var sel = editor.selection.getSel();
    var caretPos = sel.anchorOffset;
    var txtData = sel.anchorNode.textContent;
    
    if(caretPos === 2 && (txtData === "* " || txtData === "- "))
    {
        if(sel.focusNode.parentElement.constructor.name === "HTMLParagraphElement")
        {
            // TODO: Somehow change this line to a <li>
        }
    }   
});
```

The code does fine identifying the text, but I'm not sure what to put in place of the TODO.  How do I change the selected text to be a

inside a ?   (Maybe there is there a cleaner way to do what I am attempting?)

Answer (score 1):

There is one plugin that can work to achieve a similar result: the [Autocompleter plugin](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/ui-components/autocompleter/#howtocreatecustomautocompleters). It can load a toolbar item like a bulleted list, which users can then select after they type "*"

You can set up the plugin to activate on a specific trigger character. If you'd like to use "* " and "- ", first add in an array with the `Bulleted List` item, and then

```
/* The autocompleter that allows you to use a character */
    editor.ui.registry.addAutocompleter('Menubar-item-variable', {
      ch: '*',
      minChars: 0, /** Zero value means that the menu appears as soon as you type the "*" */
      columns: 1,
      fetch: function (pattern) {
            const matchedActions = insertActions.filter(function (action) {
            return action.type === 'separator' ||
            action.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(pattern.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
            });

            return new tinymce.util.Promise(function (resolve) {
                var results = matchedActions.map(function (action) {
                    return {
                        meta: action,
                        text: action.text,
                        icon: action.icon,
                        value: action.text,
                        type: action.type
                    }
                });
                resolve(results);
            });
        },
        onAction: function (autocompleteApi, rng, action, meta) {
            editor.selection.setRng(rng);
            editor.execCommand('Delete');
            meta.action();
            autocompleteApi.hide(); 
        }
    });
    return {};
});
```

There is some blog content about the Autocompleter: https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/slash-commands-rich-text-editor/

Comment: Thank you!   That's an interesting workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I ended up solving it.   In the Editor's onInit function, I did this:

```
editor.on('KeyUp', function(e){
    var sel = editor.selection.getSel();
    var caretPos = sel.anchorOffset;
    var txtData = sel.anchorNode.textContent;
    
    // if the user types '* ' or '- ' inside a paragraph then convert to a bullet
    // Note that the character from &nbsp; is different that an ascii space.  That's
    // why the match has two spaces in the 2nd character place.  They are actually 
    // different character codes. 
    if(e.key === ' ' && caretPos === 2 && (txtData.match(/^[*-][  ]/)))
    {
        if(sel.focusNode.parentElement.constructor.name === "HTMLParagraphElement")
        {
            sel.focusNode.parentElement.outerHTML = `<ul><li>${txtData.substr(2)}</li></ul>`
        }
    }                        
});
```