# How do you add auto-bullets in TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-5

Many apps (such as Slack) have a handy feature where if you type a hyphen `-` and hit space on a new line, the line will automatically be transformed into a bullet (aka unordered list). How does one accomplish this functionality in TinyMCE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad you asked! I went through a few iterations on this solution before finding one that seemed to work pretty well.

First, I defined both the trigger character for Autobullets (hyphen), and the HTML containers within which I'd like Autobullet to be triggered (in this case, paragraphs, divs, table cells, and spans):

```
const AUTOBULLET_TRIGGER_CHARACTER = "-";
const AUTOBULLET_VALID_CONTAINERS = [
  "HTMLTableCellElement",
  "HTMLParagraphElement",
  "HTMLDivElement",
  "HTMLElement",
];
```

Then, I added this event handler in the editor setup, with comments:

```
        editor.on("KeyUp", function (e) {
          var sel = editor.selection.getSel();
          var caretPos = sel.anchorOffset;
          var txtData = sel.anchorNode.textContent;
          
          // Char code 160 is a non breaking space
          const lineMatch = `${AUTOBULLET_TRIGGER_CHARACTER}${String.fromCharCode(
            160
          )}`;

          if (e.key === " " && caretPos === 2 && txtData === lineMatch) {
            if (
              AUTOBULLET_VALID_CONTAINERS.includes(
                sel.focusNode.parentElement.constructor.name
              )
            ) {
              // Create an unordered list
              editor.execCommand("InsertUnorderedList", false);

              // Delete the last two characters from the cursor position,
              // which we know are "- " since that's what triggered the autobullet
              //
              // Modified from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43798749
              const edRange = editor.selection.getRng();
              const edNode = edRange.commonAncestorContainer;
              let range = document.createRange(); // create a new range object for the deletion
              range.selectNodeContents(edNode);
              range.setStart(edNode, edRange.endOffset - 2); // current caret pos - 3
              range.setEnd(edNode, edRange.endOffset); // current caret pos
              range.deleteContents();
            }
          }
        });
```

As you can see, the handler detects whether or not on `keyUp` the user has triggered the character and space. Then, we insert the unordered list (critically, we use the `InsertUnorderedList` command, as inserting a raw `ul` and `li` seems to break the list functionality) and remove the hyphen/space triggers.

Comment: I'll give credit to this answer for pointing me in the right direction; however I didn't find that this exact solution worked very well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68578376/353878

Answer (score 1):

As an FYI, the `textpattern` plugin in TinyMCE gives you a way to insert lists using (by default) markup style text:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/textpattern/

The list specific options are:

```
// The following text patterns require the `lists` plugin
{start: '1. ', cmd: 'InsertOrderedList'},
{start: '* ', cmd: 'InsertUnorderedList'},
{start: '- ', cmd: 'InsertUnorderedList' }
```

This requires no coding to implement and allows you to determine the text that can start a list.  The example above allows a list to start with an asterisk or dash but you can customize that list to your needs.

Comment: Wow, I feel kind of stupid now. I searched and searched both docs and SO for answers and somehow never found this. Thanks for the answer!